# Problem with GtkTextBuffer , Confusing Runtime Error. Need Help?

Tags: c++, c, gtk, runtime-error

I am using this code:

```
class editbook
{
  GtkWidget* _nbook;
  std::vector<GtkWidget*> _srcset; //and so on...
```

...........................................................................................

```
void editbook::add_page()
{
    GtkWidget* tmp = gtk_source_view_new();
    _srcset.push_back(tmp);
    gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(_nbook),tmp,gtk_label_new("untitled"));
}
```

...........................................................................................

```
void editbook::set_text(const std::string& text)
{
    int index = gtk_notebook_get_current_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(_nbook));
    GtkTextBuffer* tbuffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(_srcset[index]));
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text(GTK_TEXT_BUFFER(tbuffer),text.c_str(),-1);
}
```

Compiles fine. But gives this weird runtime error:

Segementation Fault: return 139

I have traced down the problem to: `gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(_srcset[index]));`

NOTE: I am using GtkSourceView instead of GtkTextView, but that may not be a problem because I am gettin the same error when I try GtkTextView.

NOTE: I am using Gtk 2x

NOTE: I am not sure whether to tag this question with C or C++. bec. Gtk+ is a C lib. But I am using C++. So I'll just tag both for now.

Comment: Could you post what is `_srcset` array? Btw why don't you use `GtkMM` ( http://www.gtkmm.org/en/ ) which is C++ wrapper over `Gtk` in case you want to write your code in C++?

Comment: @another.anon.coward `std::vector<GtkWidget*> _srcset` . Filled with GtkSourceViews (gtk_source_view_new()); As for GtkMM. Frankly I don't use it because I am an idiot... And because It doesn't compile on Ubuntu for some reason (glibmmconfig.h not found)

Comment: You're not showing enough information. Tell us where you define _srcset and why `_srcset[index]` must be a valid reference at the time of execution.

Comment: @sehe Now do you have enough info?

Comment: Hmmm ... Did you check if buffer returned for `NULL` & if they are valid objects? I mean what is the output for `GTK_IS_TEXT_VIEW(_srcset[index])` & `GTK_IS_TEXT_BUFFER(tbuffer)`? Also, I would suggest you please use `vector::at`  instead of `operator[]` just to be sure that you are not going out of the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code could be that the child widget added to `GtkNotebook` through `gtk_notebook_append_page` is not *visible*, try showing the child widget through `gtk_widget_show` call. Something on these lines :

```
void editbook::add_page()
{
    GtkWidget* tmp = gtk_source_view_new();
    _srcset.push_back(tmp);
    gtk_widget_show(tmp); //Show the child widget to make it visible
    gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(_nbook),tmp,gtk_label_new("untitled"));
}
```

When you use `gtk_notebook_get_current_page` if none of the child widget are visible then it returns `-1`, which I think might be happening in your case & as `index` is `-1` when you use `operator[]` which doesn't check for bounds the program crashes. I strongly suggest you use `vector::at` instead of using `operator[]` so that you get `std::out_of_range` exception during run time to indicate the problem. You could use:

```
void editbook::set_text(const std::string& text)
{
    int index = gtk_notebook_get_current_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(_nbook));
    GtkTextBuffer* tbuffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(_srcset.at(index)));
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text(GTK_TEXT_BUFFER(tbuffer),text.c_str(),-1);
}
```

Hope this helps!